# Wronskian of $x^3$ and $x^2 |x|$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question is fairly straight forward, given $2$ functions $y_1=x^3$ and $y_2=x^2|x|$ determine whether the functions are linearly dependent or independent.

I am conflicted because in my differential equations textbook it states that two functions are linearly independent if their quotient is a non-constant function for all $x$. Here it is evident that for $x<0$ the quotient $\frac{y1}{y2} = 1$ while for $x<0$, $\frac{y1}{y2}=-1$. This would lead to a conclusion that the functions are linearly independent.

However, in the textbook it is also stated that two linearly dependent functions will have a Wronskian of zero on the real number line.

So the Wronskian $W(y_1(x), y_2(x)) = \det \begin{vmatrix}y_1(x)& y_2(x)\\ y_1'(x)& y_2'(x) \end{vmatrix}$ and $y_1'(x) = 3x^2$

the derivative of $y_2'(x)$ is slightly more tricky but checking with wolfram alpha
$y_2'(x)=\frac{3x^3}{|x|}$

so the Wronskian is given by:

$$W=y_1(x)y_2'(x)-y_2(x)y_1'(x)=x^3\times\frac{3x^3}{|x|}-x^2|x|\times3x^2$$

Now multiplying the second term by $\frac{|x|}{|x|}$ in order to add the terms yields

$$W=\frac{3x^6}{|x|}-3x^4\times \frac{|x|^2}{|x|}$$

At this point I assume $|x|^2=x^2$

which yields:

$$W=\frac{3x^6}{|x|}-\frac{3x^6}{|x|}=0 $$

This would imply the functions are linearly dependent....

The answer provided by the textbook states that the functions are linearly independent. Does anyone have some words of wisdom for me :)

Cheers

Comment: If you simply put dollar signs around your math equations they will format much better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The theorem says **if** the functions are linearly dependent, **then** the Wronskian is $0$.  It does not state that if the Wronskian is $0$, the functions are linearly dependent.  These functions  are an example 
that shows this.  Their Wronskian is $0$, and they would be linearly dependent if you just looked at the interval $(-\infty, 0)$ or $(0, \infty)$, but they are not linearly dependent on the whole real line
because neither is a constant multiple of the other.

The point (which will probably be made later) is that solutions of homogeneous second-order linear differential equations are rather special: if they are linearly dependent in some interval, this same linear dependence holds over the whole interval where the differential equation is defined; moreover, the value of the Wronskian at one point tells the whole story.

Comment: Thank you, this was a perfect explanation. I guess this is a downside of the textbook I am using in which it was written that:

"If y1 and y2 are linearly independent, then W(y1, y2) does not equal 0 at each point of I . "

Seems like a rather large error on their part unless I am skimming over the text to fast and missed some other explanation.

Comment: Such a perfect answer. Thanks a lot sir !!

Comment: @Filip I'm afraid you are skimming over the text too fast. I guess the book which you were referring to was " Differential Equations and Boundary value problems by Henry Edwards, Penney, Calvis". The theorem does say " If y1 and y2 are linearly independent then W(y1,y2)≠0 at each point of I" but that's only part of the theorem. Infact, y1 are y2 are not just some random functions, "they are the two solutions of 2nd order homogeneous diff eqn. y"+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0 on I and p and q are continuous on I" This hypothesis must also be true for the conclusion "Wronskian is everywhere nonzero" to follow.

Comment: Since you have already found that W(y1,y2)=0 for some point in R which is clear negation of "W(y1,y2)≠0 at each point of R" without using the theorem, that means the hypotheses(for (b) part of Theorem 3) can't be true otherwise the theorem would be wrong. Of course, the theorem isn't wrong since the hypotheses is not satisfied. y1 and y2 being linearly independent does not follow the other hypothesis, i.e x³ and |x³| can never be solutions of eqn y"+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0 on R where p and q are continuous on R. You may see Q.30 Exercise 3.1 for one such case.@Filip

Comment: @AmanKushwaha Do you realize you are replying to a posting from 2015?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I do. It's true that the post is very old and the user who asked this question might have nothing to do with it now. But there are others who could visit this page and may get confused and end up believing that the book has some error. So I just thought it's better to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Since |x| is not a differentiable function, you get a weird result. If we consider the definition of linear dependency:

$$c_1x^3+c_2 x^2|x|=0$$

It is clear that no $c_1,c_2$ satisfies this expression so the functions are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

If I consider two functions $x^3$ and $x^2|x|$ in the interval $[-1,1]$, then their wronskian vanishes identically, but they are linearly independent in that interval. What is the proper reason behind this? I saw one said that two functions are linearly dependent implies their wronskian vanishes identically, but the converse is not true...but I want to ask the reference book of this statement because it violates all the standard books like Ross etc..

Answer (score 0):

If the Wronskian is not equal to zero for some x in I, then the functions are linearly independent on the interval. Also if the functions are linearly dependent on I, then the  Wronskian is equal to zero for all x in the interval I. But W=0 does not mean the functions are dependent.

Comment: This answer does not add anything to Robert Israel's already accepted answer.